# Объясните функцию step()

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Объясните как работает функция step() для вышеописанной задачи, что делает каждая строка этой функции. Заранее спасибо.

```
def step(k):
    s = 0
    for h in k: 
        s ^= h #?
    if s == 0:
        return k.index(max(k)), 1 #?
    for i in range(len(k)):
        if 0 <= k[i] ^ s < k[i]: #?
            return i, k[i] - (k[i] ^ s)#?
    return k.index(max(k)), 1 #?


cnt = 3
k, s = [0] + [int(input()) for _ in range(cnt)], True
while sum(k):
    s = not s
    if s:
        while True:
            h, n = int(input()), int(input())
            if 0 < h <= cnt and 0 < n <= k[h]: 
                break
            print('Некорректный ход:', h, n)
    else:
        h, n = step(k)
    k[h] -= n
    print(h, n, *k[1:])
print('Вы выиграли!' if s else 'ИИ выиграл!')
```

Comment: sorry,  вот строка `s = 0`, скажите пожалуйста, что вам в ней не понятно?

Comment: @S.Nick в ней все ясно, но далее идут циклы , вычисления для меня непонятные

Comment: какая именно строка вам не понятна?

Comment: @S.Nick сейчас возле непонятных строк в вопросе напишу комментарий с знаком вопроса

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
s ^= h #?
```

битовое исключающее ИЛИ (XOR) с присвоением результата той-же переменной.

```
k.index(max(k)), 1 #?
```

возврат индекса максимального элемента в списке.

```
0 <= k[i] ^ s < k[i]: #?
```

проверка соответствующего условия, явно написанного в строке.

```
return i, k[i] - (k[i] ^ s)#?
```

попытка возврата двух значений, i  и того что получиться после выполнения действия, описанного после запятой.

Comment: а еще один return?

Comment: @ Ой как все запущено....  А понять, что делает последний, учитывая что он на 99% состоит из того, что объяснено в двух предыдущих -  самому никак?